# Sending Variables to MySQLi

Tags: php, variables, mysqli

i have been staring at this page for half an hour trying to figure out where i am going wrong. The first two variables are found and inserted into database, however the last two, 'email' and 'password' are not found, not inserted into database but still however pass the if statement. Any help will be much appreciated.

Form.php

```
        <form name="signup" method="POST" action="signup.php">

        <label for="signupFirstName">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="signupFirstName" name="signupFirstName" />
        <label for="signupLastName">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="signupLastName" name="signupLastName"/>

        <label for="signupEmail">Email</label>
        <input type="text" id="signupEmail" name="signupEmail" />
        <label for="signupConfirmEmail">Confirm Email</label>
        <input type="text" id="signupConfirmEmail" name="signupConfirmEmail"/>

        <label for="signupPassword">Password</label>
        <input type="text" id="signupPassword" name="signupPassword"/>
        <label for="signupConfirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="text" id="signupConfirmPassword" name="signupConfirmPassword"/>

        <button name="submit" type="submit" >Submit Form</button>

        </form>
```

signup.php

```
     <?php
    if (isset($_POST['signupFirstName']) || isset($_POST['signupLastName']) ||     isset($_POST['signupEmail']) || isset($_POST['signupPassword']) ) {

    echo $_POST['signupEmail'];
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user1', 'password', 'db2');

    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
    }

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO members (First_Name, Last_Name, Email, Password) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('ssss',$sample,$lastName,$email,$password);


    // escape the POST data for added protection
    $sample = isset($_POST['signupFirstName'])
        ? $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['signupFirstName'])
        : '';
    $lastName = isset($_POST['signupLastName'])
        ? $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['signupLastName'])
        : '';     
    $email = isset($_POST['signupEmail'])
        ? $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['signupEmail'])
        : '';
    $password = isset($_POST['signupPassword'])
        ? $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['signupPassword'])
        : '';


    /* execute prepared statement */
    $stmt->execute();

    printf("%d Row inserted.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);

    /* close statement and connection */
    $stmt->close();

    /* close connection */
    $mysqli->close();
}
    else{
    echo "broken";
    }
?>
```

Comment: DON'T ESCAPE BIND VARIABLES (it doesn't "add protection", it simply injects spurious escape characters); and set the variable values __before__ binding them

Comment: We won't even comment about storing passwords in plain text at this point, not until you get the insert actually working; but simply recommend that it's __very__ bad practise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be binding the params to your query before you actually set the variables. Move the  `bind_param()` call above the `execute()` call.

You can also refactor your code to take out a lot of the junk. Example below:

```
<?php
function arr_get($array, $key) {
    if (isset($array[$key])) {
        return $array[$key];
    }

    return '';
}

if (isset($_POST['signupFirstName']) || isset($_POST['signupLastName']) || isset($_POST['signupEmail']) || isset($_POST['signupPassword']) ) {

    echo $_POST['signupEmail'];
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user1', 'password', 'db2');

    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO members (First_Name, Last_Name, Email, Password) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('ssss', arr_get($_POST, 'signupFirstName'), arr_get($_POST, 'signupLastName'), arr_get($_POST, 'signupEmail'), arr_get($_POST, 'signupPassword'));

    /* execute prepared statement */
    $stmt->execute();

    printf("%d Row inserted.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);

    /* close statement and connection */
    $stmt->close();

    /* close connection */
    $mysqli->close();

}
else {
    echo "broken";
}
?>
```